# How can I animate a colour change over hue/saturation/value instead of RGB in Blender?

Tags: graphics, blender

If I create a keyframe for a colour in Blender (I'm using 2.6) it always seems to traverse the RGB values for the animation, even if I set the colour using HSV values.

I do this by setting the colour, using HSV, then pressing <kbd>i</kbd> over it.

How can I animate the HSV values rather than the RGB values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by using material nodes. If you use a `Hue Saturation Value` node in your node setup, you can animate any of the `HSV` values with the same method as you described (pressing <kbd>i</kbd> key over the field that should be animated).

[image: hvs animation in blender using nodes]

In the screenshot you can see a possible setup. I'm using a `HSV` node as the input for the materials color. I set the base color-value of the `HSV` node to `0.5, 1.0, 1.0` (cyan blue), as this seems to produce correct output colors then (eg. a hue of 0.0 or 1.0 is red).